# unknown class in native SQL using Hibernate

Tags: hibernate, jakarta-ee, hibernate-mapping

I have a `bean` class which in **Not** `mapped` to a `database` `table`.
I have used `createSqlQuery` and `addEntity` for `mapping the result set`. but the `error` is: `unknown entity`.
I used `setResultSetMapping` and the `error` is `unknown entity.`
The `bean` class have been introduced in `hibernate.cfg.xml`.

thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Check your mapping - you might have a reference to an unknown class (CodeTemplate).

Answer (score 0):

There two ways of solution

1st way :

You have to add `@Entity` on `Pojo` class,which makes your pojo as JPA entity .

Second ,Using configuration :

You should use AnnotationConfiguration instead of Configuration and then call

```
 configuration.addAnnotatedClass(YourClass.class);
```

refer [@Entity](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/5/api/javax/persistence/Entity.html)

```
    Specifies that the class is an entity. This annotation is applied 
    to the entity class.
```